# Assign a random number from range X for each element in list Y

Tags: python, random

I need to assign a random number from a range X for each element in list Y while minimizing the number of duplicated numbers from X.

To clarify, I do not want a situation where I have an excess of number *i* from X while number *j* from X is not used.

In their a computational efficient way to this? I'm happy to use a library.

Comment: *Minimizing duplications* yet *keeping it random*…? Well, which is it?

Comment: From X, I do not want an excess of number *i* while number *j* is not used

Comment: So you want to distribute the range in its entirety first, and then repeat when it's exhausted?

Comment: Shuffle the range, pop it till it's empty, then start again…? Or just concat as many shuffled ranges until you have enough elements?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: How strictly balanced? It might be worth trying to do `collections.Counter(random.choices(range(10), k=100))` a few times and see if that might just be enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to deceze's suggest in comments - you could make a basic generator that repeatedly shuffles and then yields elements from the shuffled list and it'd be something like:

```
from random import shuffle
from itertools import islice
from collections import Counter

def shuffler(obj):
    lst = list(obj)
    while True:
        shuffle(lst)
        yield from lst

shuffled = shuffler(range(7))
```

Then you can either `islice` from it:

```
random100 = list(islice(shuffled, 100))
# distro100 = Counter(random100)
# Counter({0: 15, 2: 14, 3: 14, 1: 14, 6: 14, 5: 14, 4: 15})
```

(possibly) use it again:

```
random14 = list(islice(shuffled, 14))
# distro14 = Counter(random14)
# Counter({6: 3, 4: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 0: 2, 5: 2, 1: 1})
```

Although, you may want to reset it again to get a perfect all-2 distro depending.

Or zip with your other list:

```
pairs = list(zip(other_list, shuffled))
```